Rate limit error while using Azure chat playground with data source and system message
I am trying to create a chat where I expect AI to respond from my provided content.I have uploaded the content, indexed and the same is availabe through serach service.
The model I am using is GPT-35-turbo(0125)
Data source: Azure AI Search
I also have the increaded quota 100k tokens/min

I am trying out chat playground by configuring search service index in add data. I also have system instruction added.
I am getting rate limt error
Error
An error occurred when calling Azure OpenAI: Server responded with status 429. Error message: {'error': {'code': '429', 'message': 'Rate limit is exceeded. Try again in 10 seconds.'}}
Hw can I resolve this or is there any way around
